# How to connect remote hbase from ubuntu virtual machine java app?

Tags: ubuntu, hbase

I am trying to connect hbase running on a linux server in a VPN from ubuntu virtual machine running on windows locally. My java code looks as below:

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    Path hbaseSitePath = new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml");
    config.addResource(hbaseSitePath);
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "10.4.2.103");

    HBaseAdmin hadmin = null;
    try{
        hadmin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
    }
```

Though it could establish a connection to zookeeper,, get hbase Master is failing with IOException.

```
INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server eg100appram003.eg100.ctcs.nl/10.4.2.103:2181, sessionid = 0x255d8e2cde11f68, negotiated timeout = 180000

INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1007
java.io.IOException: Call to eg100appram003.eg100.ctcs.nl/10.4.2.103:60000 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.wrapException(HBaseClient.java:1056)
```

One obvious doubt was, I am not providing username/password to the linux server on which zookeeper and hbase are running.
was it a reason for exception?  If so, how can I do that?  or am I missing any other configurations?

Any insights please...

Answer (score 0):

Do not know your version of hbase but maybe setting the master address in the conf.

```
hbase.master.info.bindAddress
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: hbase(main):001:0> version
0.90.6-cdh3u4, r, Mon May  7 13:14:00 PDT 2012

Comment: I set the value to 10.4.2.103., but it did not help

Comment: Does the virtual machine allow connections on that port?